# UITextContentType.OneTimeCode in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

i'm trying to implement the OTC into my app. I'm doing the next:

```
_txtField = new UITextField()
{
   UserInteractionEnabled = true,
   TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode
};
_txtFieldDelegate = new UITextFieldDelegate();
_txtField.Delegate = _txtFieldDelegate;
```

I got the SMS, but i have nothing to fill the TextField, what more i need to get this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly,`OneTimeCode` is available after iOS 12.0.So,add the following code

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(12, 0))
{
  _txtField.TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode;          
}
```

And set the textField as `BecomeFirstResponder` after you send the request of get SMS.

```
 _txtField.BecomeFirstResponder();
```

Then the SMS code will appear on the keyboard.And it will auto fill when you click it.

Comment: it works, but the main problem was the SMS, the key "Code" or "Passcode" had to be in the text.