# One Time Password On IOS App - Suggestion not appearing above keyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, passwords

I'm looking to implement where a OTP is made a suggestion at the top of the keyboard for an OTP Entry in an IOS app.
The IOS version on the phone is 12.2.
THE ISO SDK Version of my App is 12.1.
Using Visual Studio (Windows) 2017 15.9.13

Now I have done the following......

- Created an new control **public class OTPEntry : Xamarin.Forms.Entry**
- Created a renderer for the control and in this I do **Control.TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode;**
- I then use this control on a ContentPage with the correct namespace etc.

SO when I am on the form with this control, I send a text to the phone with an OTP.  On the phone if I click on the code it offers a "Copy Code" option so it is recognised as an OTP.
However, for the life of me, when I tap in the control, to bring up the keyboard, I do not see the code in the top of the keyboard as expected.

What could  I possibly be missing?
It seems the steps to implement this are relatively straightforward but I cannot seem to get it working.

Any ideas, pointers would be very greatly appreciated.

Code below...

**CONTROL - IN Xamarin Forms Project**

```
namespace XXXX
{
    public class OTPEntry : Xamarin.Forms.Entry
    {
        public OTPEntry()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**RENDERER - IN IOS Project**

```
namespace XXXX.YYYY.ZZZZ
{
    public class OTPEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode;
            }
...
...
    }
    }
}
```

**USAGE - IN CONTENT PAGE IN Xamarin Forms Project**

```
<XXXX:OTPEntry x:Name="txtToken" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Two Factor Code" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="300" TextColor="#2A295B" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0"/>
```

Comment: Yep - it does that.  Has the "Copy Code" option dialog type thingy

Comment: Can you provide a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Added code as per Lucas

Comment: You should focus the entry and then send the message . And the OTP code will appear on the keyboard.And it will auto fill when you click it.

Comment: You code seems has no issue.I create a demo and it works fine .

Comment: Does the line `Control.TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode;` been called in runtime?

Comment: I have uploaded my project here https://github.com/luczha/OneTimeCode and you can download and test .

Comment: Yes - it does hoit that code.
So when I am on that content page - I send an SMS to the phone.
Once I hear the phone beep, I tap on the field and the keyboard appears but no OTP "suggestion".
Driving me nuts!  But hey, that's what Xamarin does.

Thanks for looking anyhow.  Bit stuck on how I can proceed with this.

Comment: Here is a similar thread maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266952/uitextcontenttype-onetimecode-in-xamarin-ios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201211/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-antdc).

Comment: Sure thing Lucas - post an answer.

Comment: I have posted it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,`OneTimeCode` is available after iOS 12.0.So I suggest add the following code in **CustomRenderer**

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(12, 0))
{
  Control.TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode;          
}
```

What happens is that when an OTP message receives into the Message Inbox, iOS runs a simple text matching algorithm that determines if that message is a valid OTP message or not and based on that keep a track of it in the memory, then when the user clicks on the OTP AutoFill enabled text field in an app, iOS keyboard popup that OTP as a suggestion in the keyboard. So that your users can fill up the OTP into the app without leaving the app or going back into the Messaging app.

You need to check if the format of OTP is correct .One way to verify whether the text message captcha format is legal is to open [SMS] on the iPhone, click on the message captcha, if from the bottom of the call option copy captcha option, can indicate that it is possible;

And don't forget to open the **Autofill Passwords** in system setting ->account and password .

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

So - after verification that the code seemed to be OK and has worked for others I was beginning to think I was going crazy.

I then had a look through the phone settings and discovered "Autofill Passwords" which was turned off.
Once I turned it on, this seems to work as expected.